# SSIS - XML with row delimiter to a single column of a SQL table

Tags: ssis, csv, ssis-2012, ssis-2014

I'm trying to upload data from a CSV file into a SQL server table through SSIS package (Flat File source and OLEDB destination). This CSV has comma as column delimiter and {CR}{LF} as row delimiter. This csv file has one column which holds XML data in it. In this XML, they again used {CR}{LF} to make it as a multi-line XML and this XML is placed within a double quotes (""). Ideally, this whole XML needs to be placed in one column however {CR}{LF} makes it as a new row in my table.

Is there any method to have escape sequence and place the whole XML data into a single column?

I'm using Visual studio 2013 and connected to SQL server 2014 database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the flat-file connection manager, in the General pane, there is an option to set a `text qualifier`. If you set this to double quote (") for your file then SSIS should ignore any row delimiters that are contained between the double quotes.

There is also an `AlwaysCheckForRowDelimiters` property that could help. See [this msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140266.aspx) for more.